# paperclip – cannot upload image from iphone library

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Uploading images through paperclip to my rails app is working well from my computer. However, I am trying to upload pictures from my iPhone album when on my rails app website on my iPhone and nothing is happening. Does this have to do with image path, or what do I need to do to enable iPhone image uploads on paperclip??

Comment: Do you see any errors in `development.log`? Try to upload image from iPhone and provide output of this request from `development.log` here. It help to investigate problem.

Comment: thanks! I will try that out! ...and let you know the output